# Running a multi-module Maven web app in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I'm trying to run a multi-module Maven web app in Eclipse (EE Helios SR 1). In NetBeans one have just to click the run button. But here it's probably a little more complicated.

I've added Tomcat 7.0.26 as a server for the war module of the project. When I try running the app, in the `Servers` part of the window I see `Apache Tomcat v.7.0.26 at localhost [Started, Synchronized]`, but browser doesn't react. Does the system browser need to show the page when the app is running?

I tried to move to `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/welcome.html` (the second one should be processed by the app) when the server was started, but I got 404 error both times. I also didn't see the new folder in the `apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/`. Should Eclipse place the project there when running the application? I'd be really grateful if someone tells me what I'm missing here.

Comment: What is the context of your webapp ? usually you don't use root access like localhost:8080/welcome.html ..usually you have something like localhost:8080/context/welcome.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I know that. I tried to type context, but this also leads to 404. And I didn't do it the last time because when running in NetBeans there were no context for this multi-module project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a lot of bad experience with running web servers in Eclipse. Most of the time, this was related to unreliable class/resource reloading.

My solution was to add [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) to my app in a new module (see [Embedding Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)). This basically turns my web app into a Java application, avoiding most of the problems. It also allows me to specify a filter (written in Java) when the app should reload.

This solves all the problems with class reloading (classes and resources are never copied anywhere; they are loaded from Eclipse's bin folders), startup is much faster (we got the startup time from several minutes down to 15s) and reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still, Eclipse is so popular. :)

Comment: I'm still using Eclipse; I only avoid the error prone "Server" tab.

Comment: In recent eclipse, server tabs works really fine. It's just a matter of configuring it well. I like jetty too for its speed and small size. But if your target deployment is tomcat, developing with jetty may leads you to build stuff that works well in your eclipse but generate error when deploying in production environment.

Comment: Jetty took a couple of hours to implement, but now it works really fine. Thanks one more time. And I didn't have to create the new module, just had to add some dependencies and plugins in the pom.xml file (in the Spring web module), so you may want to edit the "new module" part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If not specified, tomcat integration with eclipse deploy by default war to a specific folder in .metadata, in my case somethings like:  `~/workspace/<my_project_workspace_name>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/`

Every war are then unzipped to a folder. If your maven pom.xml you'll find a

```
<build>
    <finalName>myapp</finalName>
</build>
```

Then it'll deployed to tomcat as :

```
localhost:8080/myapp/welcome.html
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. There was a folder, not a war. And all the libraries seem to be in it. But it didn't run when I copied it in Tomcat's webapps folder. Probably, because there were no classes from the other modules, which shoud have been in the WEB-INF/classes/ folder. Do you have any idea why? The other modules are marked in the build.

Comment: You can ask eclipse to take control of your tomcat conf. In the server tab, double click on your tomcat install, then into the Server locations section change to "Use Tomcat installation. (take control of Tomcat installation)". This way you'll have eclipse deploy things in your tomcat installation folder. Beware of folder right under linux/unix system.

Comment: I suppose it will only change the folder of the project with a lack of class files (like the project that is deployed now in .metadata). And the whole "Server Location" section is inactive, I can't edit it right now.

Comment: And, by the way, Aaron Digulla has a really good point about unreliable class/resource reloading, that made me choose his answer as the more reliable one (and also the fact the team I maybe will work with also uses jetty).

Comment: If your team use jetty, go for it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maven Projects are different from the ones with Web Application Facets, You cannot directly run a Maven App as a web app because the folder structure is different. In order to run your application directly from eclipse, try to add Web Application nature to your maven project [A complex modification involving modification of .project and .classpath files along with addition of few other files]. I would recommend modifying your pom.xml file accordingly

Comment: Oh, I see. So, how does one check the results while developing? Is it a common procedure to make these modifications? That sounds a little inconvenient.

Comment: Yeah a bit inconvenient and common, I'm not sure whether any plugins are available apart from codehaus wagon to deploy applications through maven.